# I want to change ruby version by rbenv, but I can't reset my 'which ruby'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-big-sur

I want to change ruby version by rbenv, but I can't reset my 'which ruby'.
Do anyone know how to change?

I run 'which ruby'
→ /usr/bin/ruby
I run 'rbenv'
→ 2.6.5

OS : macOS Big Sur
shell : zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure there is something like this in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Comment: Thank you !! I added the similar code in my '~/.zshrc' before... anyway, now I can change my ruby version. Thanks.